# How should the gas discharge tubes for RS-422/RS-485 be placed and routing on the PCB?

Tags: pcb, rs485, rs422

I adjusted the gas discharge tubes to be close to the connectors on the PCB. The RS-422 lines have a differential line impedance of 100 Ω. My concern is, aren't the lines between the connector and the gas discharge too thin? Do you think this will cause a problem? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Why such thin traces? What kind of surge are they absorbing? I don't have a sense of scale here *(you could mention what the dimensions are)* but it feels like they're thin enough I might be worried even about ESD, let alone any kind of (IEC 61000-4-5, various ITU, MIL, etc.) surge. Also, is there ground plane in this design?

Comment: Contains circular connector. And it was drawn so thinly to pass it between the footprints of the connectors and the impedance was calculated.

Comment: I have drawn a chassis ground around the pcb for the ground plane, but I cannot connect it to the chasis gnd because they are in the center of the pcb. For this, I will connect the middle point  to the signal gnd of gdt.

Comment: Increasing the separation between the differential pair to 3W (3 x trace width) allows you to increase trace width (as if they're two 50 Ω single-ended traces) while maintaining the 100 Ω differential impedance. If this is still not enough, it may be acceptable to use wide trace and ignore impedance entirely, at least until the signal leaves the GDT area. The large GDT pads will introduce a huge impedance discontinuity anyway, at RS-485's speed, this is possibly a non-issue.

Comment: the thickness of the trace is 0.11 mm

Comment: RS-422 has a minimum edge rate of... I don't know, at least some nanoseconds. This is not a high-speed bus, at the very least not like PCIe is high-speed. Trace impedance and pair matching are nearly irrelevant over board-sized length scales.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments, I have increased the copper layer to 1 oz. And the trace thickness will be 0.2mm, would you suggest that I completely cover the gas discharge tube and the connector with polygyon pour?

Comment: Why did you delete the photo? The comments about your design seem unrelated now.

Comment: Lines between what connector? I see an eval board. Voting close for insufficient detail.

Comment: @TimWilliams That is what I was trying to say. OP deleted a picture which showed a connector. If flagged properly, maybe as vandalism, it could be reverted back. But I wanted to hear the reason for this "vandalism", maybe it was a work related photo and no permission to post it.

Answer (score 1):

At RS422/485 speeds, the impedance of the trace is irrelevant to overall function, so trace width is not an issue.

However, your gas discharge tubes are in the right location for diverting overvoltage (from say nearby lightning strike) as early and directly as possible